# Is it possible to "overwrite a pointer" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to emulate the code below, in JavaScript?

```
var ref = new Reference();
var arr = [1, 2, ref];
ref.overwrite(3);
console.log(arr); // output: [1,2,3]
```

This code places a `ref` inside an array, then overwrites it, completely replacing its occurrence by `3`. We could do something similar by storing the parent object and the index:

```
var arr = [1, 2, null];
var ref = {object: arr, index: 2};
ref.object[ref.index] = 3;
console.log(arr); // output: [1, 2, 3]
```

But this is not the same thing, since `ref` must keep track of all the parent objects where it is used. I'm interested in using `ref` as a **placeholder**, storing it in multiple places and then replacing all occurrences by something else, without keeping track of where it was used. We could also "almost" do this as such:

```
var ref = {value: null};
var arr = [1, 2, ref];
ref.value = 3;
console.log(arr); // output: [1, 2, {value: 3}]
```

But this doesn't completely get rid of the wrapping object.

Comment: You can use js getters and setter or proxy that has access to the array

Answer (score 1):

No, JavaScript does not have *references* or *pointers* as values. You always need some wrapper object (which you can mutate however you want, but not replace), it's not possible to create a custom primitive value.

Comment: Depending on what you need this for, there are lots of abstractions that can help you with creating the wrapper objects in a way that makes them painless to use. You might want to ask a new question about that, with your specific use case.

Comment: Think of a function that generates a big array, populating it with a lot of values. Except for a few specific positions, the function doesn't have the value yet. So, a way to do it is to place `null` on those positions, and then iterate over the array once again on, replacing all occurrences of `null` by the (now known) value. I'm just wondering if it is possible to avoid the second loop with something like I described (which would allow me to place `ref` on those positions, and then just `ref.rewrite(value)`).

Comment: You could define getters for those places of the array, but getters are costly. It would be much better (more efficient, probably faster in benchmarks) to just put objects in that array. Especially if you use abstract data types, it shouldn't be too hard providing an abstraction that allows getting the final values. But as I said, please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide more context and code. Like the other answer says, there are many ways to fake it, and we cannot suggest the best one without knowing the exact use case.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to really do what you want to do, but depending on how you are using it, you can fake it. You can use valueOf to return what you want. Example here shows using it to sum up an array of numbers and than altering it and running it again.

```js
const sum = arr => arr.reduce((t, i) => t + i, 0)

function MyRef(n) {
  this.number = n;
  this.overWrite = n => this.number = n
}

MyRef.prototype.valueOf = function() {
  return this.number;
};

const ref = new MyRef(100);
const myArray = [1, 2, ref]
console.log(sum(myArray))
ref.overWrite(3)
console.log(sum(myArray))
```